# php url rewrite for form GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

i did make a rewrite URL in codeigniter fashion, basically i do write url with this schema

```
my domain / model / controller / varname / varvalue / varname / varvalue

http://mydomain.com/news/detail/idnews/2/myothervar/4/
```

and i use tho .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

the problem is that form get value are add as query string instead i would like to be queued as previous var like this

```
http://mydomain.com/news/detail/idnews/2/myothervar/4/get1/abc/get2/123/
```

Comment: @HalfCrazed why that?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. You cannot change how browsers submit GET requests -- you can always handle is via JS, but shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: can't i write a rule to convert query string to url path if i don't know variables names?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right after the `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1/%1/%2/ [L]
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to change the URL query string still there